# Mongoose Model wont fire pre("remove") hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a cascading delete hook. When the user is removed from mongo, I want associated records to be removed as well.  I can do this from within the code and with separate calls, however I am trying to use the pre remove hook.  The primary record was removed as expected however none of the actions in the pre hook were activated.

Environment:  Mongoose 7.50, Nodejs 18+

Here is the code in the main application to trigger the removal of the user.

```
    const user = User.findById(req.user._id).select("_id");
    await user.deleteOne();
```

Here is the relevant section of the user model.

```
// These functions act on the schema

// Encrypt password using bcrypt
schema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  next();
});

schema.pre("remove", async function (next) {
  // get the string value of user._id because the other tables don't use the obj id of userid.
  const userId = this._id.toString();
  console.log(" ~ file: user.js:155 ~ userId:", userId);

  console.log("we are in cascade delete");

  // remove the messages from the messages table and that will cascade to the messageswaiting table.
  await this.model("message").deleteMany({ user_id: userId });

  // remove the archive messages from the archive table.
  await this.model("archive").deleteMany({ user_id: userId });

  // freeze the username for 30 days.
  const frozen = new this.model("frozenusername")({ username: this.username });
  await frozen.save();
  next();
});
```

The console.log entries do not appear in the logs. which seem to tell me that the hook is not firing. I am not sure where to turn. The mongoose website doesn't seem to talk about the remove hook. The code doesn't error out in any way. It happily deletes the user account, just non of the related documents.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i am not sure how user.deleteOne() will be a success without awaiting the User.findById(). Your are positive that user is being deleted?

Comment: that is a good catch, I didn't even see that. I will try it.

Comment: does the name of the pre hook, in my case "remove" have to match the deleteOne? so should the hook become  pre("deleteOne" ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the query `await User.deleteOne({_id: _id})` This is called a model query.  When you execute this query, the actual document data is NOT available inside the model. So you have to first create a document, then act on the document.  This way when you are doing cascading deletes you have access to the parent _id via  this._id object. So first you start with:

```
// remove all db data. This is cascading.
const delUser = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
await delUser.deleteOne();
```

Inside the User model there are a few things you need to do. First you need to  include or require the models you are going to act on.

```
const Message = require("./message");
const Archive = require("./archive");
const Frozen = require("./frozen_username");
```

Next when you define your pre hook, the name of the hook has to match the query, in this case `deleteOne`. BTW not all model and document types are available as a hook. See here: [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware)

so here is the pre hook defined:

```
schema.pre("deleteOne", { document: true, query: false }, async function (next) {
  // get the string value of user._id because the other tables don't use the obj id of userid.
  let userId = this._id;
  userId = userId.toString();
  // remove the messages from the messages table
  await Message.deleteMany({ user_id: userId });
  // remove the archive messages from the archive table.
  await Archive.deleteMany({ user_id: userId });
  // freeze the username for 30 days.
  await Frozen.create({ username: this.username });
});
```

You will notice this part `{ document: true, query: false },`  Here deleteOne can be a document or a query. In this special hook you need to tell it which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The remove method has been deprecated, we should use deleteOne. deleteOne must then be called on the individual document when removing it, or the pre hook won't trigger.

```js
schema.pre("deleteOne", { document: true, query: false }, async function (next) {
  const userId = this._id.toString();
  await this.model("message").deleteMany({ user_id: userId });
  await this.model("archive").deleteMany({ user_id: userId });
  await this.model("frozenusername").create({ username: this.username });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.